# Test Flight Issue With Provisioning Profile

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect, testflight

I have uploaded my build to iTunes connect, and set up internal testing with TestFlight, but my testers are not receiving any invite emails, and my iTunes connect is acting odd. My build has a yellow warning sign next to it, i'm not sure why. Please tell me what I am doing wrong. I am pretty sure that it has something to do with my provisioning profile. I think the pictures below will be most helpful in terms of extra info. 
[image][image]
[image]

Comment: hover your cursor over the warning in the last image you posted, what does the message say?

Comment: @theMonster the message is odd when I hover over the warning symbol. It literally only says "1"

Comment: Strange... Did you get an email from iTC saying there was anything wrong with the binary? (also, did you check to make sure your Provisioning profile has the tesflight testing entitlement?)

Comment: Update: I clicked on the FAQ link shown in the third photo. On the FAQ link it says that "New Distribution Provisioning profiles generated in the iOS Developer Center will automatically contain the beta entitlement" and I just generated my provisioning profile a couple days ago. Could it be that this isn't working because Provisioning Profile is a development profile and not distribution?

Comment: @theMonster I will check my provisioning profile. I just posted a comment "update" that might help you figure out what my problem is.

Comment: @theMonster I have not gotten an email from iTunes connect about an issue with the binary.

Comment: Strange, try using a Distribution Provisioning profile as opposed to a development provisioning profile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your third screen shot explains why:

> To use TestFlight beta testing, build 1 must contain the correct beta entitlements.

You should follow the instructions in the FAQ link that the error message gave you.

Contrary to [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27756637/2998), you can beta test with *internal* users without review. For external beta testers, you *do* need a review, but it's less comprehensive than the one for the App Store and typically only takes a day or two.

Comment: On the FAQ link it says that "New Distribution Provisioning profiles generated in the iOS Developer Center will automatically contain the beta entitlement" and I just generated my provisioning profile a couple days ago. Could it be that this isn't working because Provisioning Profile is a development profile and not distribution?

Comment: Yes, it has to be signed with the distribution profile.